# jQuery pass array as argument in function

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to pass an array as an argument in a function

See the --> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QfsCV/8/) <--

From what I've tested it seems the function is reading the argument as a string rather than an array. How do I pass the array as an argument in the function?

HTML

```
<button id='arr1'>Click for Array 1</button>
<button id='arr2'>Click for Array 2</button><br/><br/>

<div id='mainstuff'>
    <p>When you click button, text should be added</p>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
    var arr2 = ["eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"];

    $('button').click(function() {
        var myval = $(this).attr('id');
        showstuff(myval);        
    });


    function showstuff(myval) {
        var x = "<p>The new text is " + myval[2] + "</p>";
        $('#mainstuff').append(x);
    }

});
```

EDIT: Fiddle has been updated to fix syntax errors.

Comment: You're passing a string, not an array. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I just noticed. I will update soon. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't do this. Don't try to call variables dynamically, i.e. without knowing their names. You can do it at a push in some circumstances, but it's a bad idea.

The best solution here is to use an object and square bracket notation to get a value from the object dynamically:

```
var values = {
    arr1: ["one", "two", "three"],
    arr2: ["eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"]
}

$('button').click(function() {
    var myval = this.id;
    showstuff(values[myval]);        
});
```

NB that I have changed `$(this).attr('id')` to `this.id` for much increased performance.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi "on that function call". Obviously it will be relatively minor in the grand scheme of things. [Comparison](http://jsperf.com/dom-property-vs-jquery-attr)

Comment: Thanks. What if my arrays are multi-dimensional. var arr1 = [{"x1":"one", "x2:"two", "x3":"three"},{"x4":"four","x5":"five","x6":"six"}];

Comment: @Sanya Then add that into the `values` object. Javascript objects and object access is generally fairly intuitive...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass in string values to be converted to objects directly.
Instead store your arrays as a  key-value pairs and then try to access them.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arrays = {
         arr1 : ["one", "two", "three"],
        arr2 : ["eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"]
    };

    $('button').click(function () {
        var myval = $(this).attr('id');
        showstuff(myval);
    });


    function showstuff(myval) {
        var x = "<p>The new text is " + arrays[myVal][2] + "</p>;
        $('#mainstuff').append(x);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. What if my arrays are multi-dimensional. var arr1 = [{"x1":"one", "x2:"two", "x3":"three"},{"x4":"four","x5":"five","x6":"six"}];

Comment: Replace `arrays[myVal][2]` with `arrays[myVal][0][key]` or `arrays[myVal][1][key]`

Answer (score 1):

You would have to store your array variables in a common object (or the window scope, which is bad practice) that you can retrieve later:

```
var commonObject = new Object();
commonObject.arr1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
commonObject.arr2 = ["eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"];
```

Then to retrieve that variable by string name:

```
var myval = $(this).attr('id');
showstuff(commonObject[myval]);
```

Comment: There is no real reason to keep using `new Object()` instead of the empty object literal `{}` nowadays, unless you have to support ancient, obscure browsers.